# IllegalStateException when creating markers on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, illegalstateexception

Hi I am trying to display some marker points on a Google map v2. All is good until I found this bug. For some reason if I load the map with 2 pointers on it and then close it and reload it again I get this message:

"IllegalStateException no included points"

This error appears when I call the:

```
 LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

This is how I put the points on the map:

```
    // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
    // manager.

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (Ad ad : Constants._results)
    {
        builder.include(new LatLng(ad.getLat(), ad.getLon()));
    }

    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition)
        {
            int padding = 50; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
            try{
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
                googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help out?

LogCat:

```
-30 14:11:11.267  20651-20874/com.myapp.user E/com.newrelic.agent.android﹕ Error in fireOnHarvestFinalize
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:843)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:841)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.metric.MetricStore.getAllByScope(MetricStore.java:63)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.metric.MetricStore.getAllUnscoped(MetricStore.java:74)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.HarvestDataValidator.ensureActivityNameMetricsExist(HarvestDataValidator.java:41)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.HarvestDataValidator.onHarvestFinalize(HarvestDataValidator.java:15)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.Harvester.fireOnHarvestFinalize(Harvester.java:580)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.Harvester.execute(Harvester.java:271)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.HarvestTimer.tick(HarvestTimer.java:73)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.HarvestTimer.tickIfReady(HarvestTimer.java:56)
        at com.newrelic.agent.android.harvest.HarvestTimer.run(HarvestTimer.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:279)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies here

```
 for (Ad ad : Constants._results)
    {
        builder.include(new LatLng(ad.getLat(), ad.getLon()));
    }
```

Constants._results must be empty, so there are no LatLng points in your builder. Debug and check.

Answer (score 0):

Run marker task on UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Add your marker here...
    }
});
```